# Can one turn off time sync between VirtualBox linux guests and linux host?

Tags: fedora, virtualbox, virtual-machine, synchronization

I'm trying to disable time sync between a Fedora 25 vbox guest (with Guest Additions installed) and a Fedora 25 host. VirtualBox version is 5.1.22 r115126. So far I've tried the following at the same time without success:

1. Issue the commands:

   ```
   VBoxManage setextradata <YOUR_VM_NAME> "VBoxInternal/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/GetHostTimeDisabled" 1

   VBoxManage setextradata <YOUR_VM_NAME> "VBoxInternal/TM/TSCTiedToExecution" 1
   ```

as suggested by https://superuser.com/questions/742924/is-it-possible-to-get-a-virtualbox-vm-always-start-from-same-time-if-so-how

2. Add the option `--disable-timesync` to `vboxadd-service`

as indicated by https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/2928

3. Disable all network adapters.

Am I missing anything? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=49016 where this is discussed. As you do not shut down the guest system but use snapshots instead, there was a way. I don't know if something changed in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks, as said in that thread restoring a snapshot taken when the vm is powered on worked, but shutting it down and then on didn't.